# Solving for a specific x-value from an nlsModel object

Tags: r, equation-solving, nls

I am fitting a model in R by passing an `SSasymp` function to `nls()`:

```
fit <- nls(y ~ SSasymp(log10(x), yf, y0, log_alpha), data = df)
```

I would like to find the intersection of this curve with the line `y = 0.1`.  I.e., where these two functions meet:

[image: Intersection of decay function with line y=0.1]

However, when I run:

```
xVal <- predict(fit,list(y = 0.1))
```

Instead of a single x-value, I get a vector of 56 values, as well as values for `yf`, `y0`, and `log_alpha`:

```
> str(xVal)
 num [1:56] 0.609 0.585 0.538 0.509 0.494 ...
 - attr(*, "gradient")= num [1:56, 1:3] 0.108 0.14 0.204 0.244 0.265 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "yf" "y0" "log_alpha"
```

I can get the estimates for the model parameters:

```
> summary(fit)

Formula: y ~ SSasymp(log10(x), yf, y0, log_alpha)

Parameters:
          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
yf        -0.04421    0.01398  -3.164  0.00258 ** 
y0         0.68735    0.01175  58.519  < 2e-16 ***
log_alpha -1.80647    0.05352 -33.753  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

And can plug these in, after solving for x by hand:

```
x = ((Asym - R0)/(Asym - 0.1))^(exp(-lrc)*log(10))
```

But I'm wondering if there is a way to use `predict()`, or a similar function, to remove the need for all this algebra!

Comment: Check out `?uniroot`

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this other than writing a function for the rearranged equation and feeding in the fit parameters?

Comment: Nope.  I ended up doing exactly that: just solved the re-arranged formula with the model parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the estimates, shouldn't something like this work?

`x[which(SSasymp(log10(x), yf, y0, log_alpha) == 0.1)]`

Comment: What is x a vector of in this case?  In my question, x is just the answer, after solving the equation for x, and plugging in 0.1. Before doing this, all I have is the nlsObject "fit".